# After Ubuntu update I see pink vertical lines on my display

Tags: 20.04, updates, display

I have a old laptop and have Ubuntu 20.04 on it, I did some Ubuntu base update and after it I see a lots on vertical pink lines in my laptop, not sure if its related to update or my display has become faulty, can anyone share any insight?

[image]

Comment: I’ve seen this before. Sadly, it’s usually due to a bad screen. It may be a coincidence that it occurred when you upgraded. Just to make sure, create a usb with an older version of Ubuntu such as 18.04. Boot into the Live Environment. If you still see the pink vertical lines, it is a hardware issue.